# How to Redirect All Requests to One Domain using AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am using a Load Balancer with Elastic Beanstalk. I want to redirect any host that is different than domain.com to `domain.com`.

Is that possible to achieve with an AWS load balancer?

Comment: Set the default target to your EB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite easy and fully supported by the AWS ALB.

What you're looking to do is to add a Host header based rule. The steps below should be followed:

- Find your Application Load Balancer
- For each listener select `View/Edit Rules`
- Click the `+` symbol at the top of the console to add your rule, specify that the rule is a host header rule with a target of your target group.
- Edit the default rule, remove the action and set to a redirect action (as show in the below screenshot).

[image]

By adding the [host header rule](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) with a target as the target group for you app, it will only connect to your hosts for the correct host name.

Otherwise have the default action be a redirect action to redirect to the domain you specify.